# Selenium - How to confirm that captcha with two numbers are changed after submit

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find any help about my problem, but unsuccessful. I need to confirm that captcha (two numbers) is changed after invalid submits. Two numbers are located in span tag (you can open this URL and see https://www.ultimateqa.com/filling-out-forms/).

Steps:

1. Open https://www.ultimateqa.com/filling-out-forms/
2. Fill out the form on the right, but intentionally enter -1 as a result of addition
3. Submit the form and confirm that the numbers have changed

I resolved first two steps, but I blocked with 3rd. Could someone please help me to resolve this problem?

```
package zadaci;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class zadatak1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\DriversSelenium\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com/filling-out-forms/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"et_pb_contact_name_1\"]")).sendKeys("TestName");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"et_pb_contact_message_1\"]")).sendKeys("TestMessage");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/p/input")).sendKeys("-1");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/p/span")).getText();

        driver.close();

            System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Your question **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the line of code that you have to use the before clicking submit and after clicking submit. Then compare they are not matching.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='et_pb_contact_captcha_question']")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this code above and added compare method. Could you please take a look if this is ok?

```
package zadaci;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class zadatak1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\DriversSelenium\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com/filling-out-forms/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"et_pb_contact_name_1\"]")).sendKeys("TestName");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"et_pb_contact_message_1\"]")).sendKeys("TestMessage");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/p/input")).sendKeys("-1");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='et_pb_contact_captcha_question']")).getText();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/button")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='et_pb_contact_captcha_question']")).getText();

        if("expected String".equals("actual string"))
           {
              System.out.println("Numbers are the same! ");
           }
         else
          {
              System.out.println("Numbers are changed! ");
          }

        driver.close();

            System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");

    }


    }
```

Thank you